# Explanation for this diamond notation?

Tags: java, generics, diamond-operator

From a official Java JDK1.7 guide, I got this quote, but I don't understand how it works.  Can anyone explain?   In other words, how does the diamond infer a Integer type when its passed an empty String?

> ```
> MyClass<Integer> myObject = new MyClass<>("");
> ```
>
> In this example, the compiler infers the type Integer for the formal
>   type parameter, X, of the generic class MyClass. It infers the type
>   String for the formal type parameter, T, of the constructor of this
>   generic class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quote indicates that there is a generic constructor in your class, which declares it's own type parameter. This is similar to how you create a generic method. The type parameter for the constructor is inferred from the argument you are passing while instantiating the class.

Here is a simple version of a class that matches that invocation:

```
 class MyClass<T> {
    <S> MyClass(S arg) {
        System.out.println(arg);
    }
 }
```

Now when you instantiate your class as in your code, the type parameter `T` is inferred as `Integer`, and type parameter `S` in constructor is inferred as `String`, from the argument you passed.

As for the diamond operator, from Java 7 onwards, you don't need to give the type arguments on while creating an instance of a generic class if you already are assigning a reference to a reference. The type argument will be inferred from the one used with the reference type, here `Integer`.

Comment: I understand the MyClass<T> part and I understand the "<S> MyClass(S arg)" part but I do not understand how System.out.println(arg);  somehow has anything to do with the type "T".  Wouldn't you need a "return Integer" type of thing?

Comment: @djangofan Yes. The difference is in scope. The scope of `T` is the entire class (all the non-static members, of course), while the scope of `S` is just the constructor.

Comment: @djangofan A constructor doesn't return anything. It's job is to initialize the object. Internally, the constructor is converted to an instance method with return type `void`.

Comment: Both of your comments make perfect sense.  I still don't quite understand though; let me guess:  The resulting Integer object called "MyClass" has a default value of 0 regardless of the string passed to it ?

Comment: @djangofan If you have an instance variable of type `T` like - `T obj;` in your class, then for `Integer` type argument, it will have it's default value `null`. It won't be `0`. You can try adding a field, and a getter for it. Then call the getter for the instance.

Comment: @djangofan Why don't you play around with the class, and see what behaviours you see. That way you will learn better.

Answer (score 8):

The `Integer` part is inferred from the usage of the *result* of the constructor call - it's assigning to a variable of type `MyClass<Integer>`, hence the `Integer` part is inferred for the diamond. The constructor argument is irrelevant to this (unless it had to be the same type, in which case you'd just get a compilation error.)

Basically, if the type argument is clear from the context in which the expression is used (where "clear" means "following precise rules" of course) then the compiler will infer it.

Comment: Ok. That makes sense.  They didn't show the return type of MyClass.  Does this imply that the constructor of MyClass contains a "return Integer" in it?  It would have made more sense to me if the right hand side said "new MyClass<>("").getInt();"

Comment: @djangofan: There's no "return type" - you're calling a constructor. A constructor always returns the type whose constructor you're calling.